# Intermediate C : String search in a large file

Tags: c, network-programming, file-handling, packet-capture, packet-sniffers

I'm writing a 'C' code that stores the TCP payload of captured packets in a file (payload of each packet is separated by multiple "\n" characters). Using C, is it possible to search for a particular string in the file after all the packets are captured?

P.S : The file can be very large, depending upon the number of captured packets.

Comment: Why you want to search the file after being written, the incoming packets are being written into a buffer, I guess, can't you just search that?

Comment: Aren't your TCP packets allowed to contain multiple `\n` bytes in a row as payload?

Comment: Errr.... yes, it is possible.

Comment: @SouravGhosh The buffer contains the entire packet (with the ethernet, ip and tcp headers)  I intend to extract the URL and print it.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Could you tell me how it is done?

Comment: @Gerhardh Yea, some of the packets do contain multiple '\n'

Comment: @nivedithanatarajan I won't write your code for you. Look at the answer below which might be what you want.

Comment: I am not sure if that is your requirement to write the data to file , you can buffer it and the buffer itself you could check if the required string available using memcmp ?

Comment: @nivedithanatarajan Then your idea separating packets with line breaks wont't work very well..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file line by line and search using strstr.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
FILE * fp;
char * line = NULL;
size_t len = 0;
ssize_t read;
char * pos;
int found = -1;

fp = fopen("filename", "r");
if (fp == NULL)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

while ((read = getline(&line, &len, fp)) != -1) 
   {
      pos = strstr(line,"search_string");
      if(pos != NULL)
      {
          found = 1;
          break;
      }
   }

if(found==1)
    printf("Found");
else
    printf("Not Found");

fclose(fp);

if (line)
    free(line);

exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```